# How can use session

Tags: 8, sessions

I created a html page and create form on it . I want send data of my form to a form that I create . I use session but when I use session and refresh page , other session was delete or when i use `session_unset();` the sessions in 4 or 5 time refresh age was show .

What is the right way for save session for anonymous users?

I use `$_SESSION['test']` but I think that it's not good way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get form content that is outdated since 4 or 5 refreshes this could be a caching issue. You can try to add a cache context to the form:

```
$form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';
```

Or if this doesn't help disable the render cache for the form:

```
$form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks . But I have many sessions . So how can I use that ? $_SESSION['a'][$loop] , $_SESSION['b'][$loop]  , $_SESSION['c'][$loop] . And $loop = 0 and with for I crease that ( $loop++).

Comment: This is one session, it doesn't matter how much data you store.